# Bash script getting the items from the third column to the last and enumerating the result

Tags: bash, for-loop, cat

I have a script which needs to read from a file, that file is always made up like:

```
bench toast pepperoni bacon
fruit berry banana
doom happy winter mountain kiwi
```

The code below, gets me from the **third** column to the **end** of the document, so the result is:

`cat file | awk -v n=3 '{ for (i=n; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}'`

```
pepperoni bacon
banana
mountain kiwi
```

My question is, how can I implement a counting variable for each element so the result shows as:

```
(1) pepperoni bacon
(2) banana
(3) mountain kiwi
so on...
```

Comment: if the 'counting variable' is just the line number from the file you can reference the `awk` variable `FNR` (File Record Number); you can also eliminate the `cat file` by feeding the file directly to `awk`, eg: `awk -v n=3 '{ printf "(%s) ", FNR ; for (i=n; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}' file`

Comment: Note that `read _ _ rest` will put the third-and-later words into `$rest`. You don't need awk, and you don't need arrays.

Comment: (Also, you _really_ don't need `cat`; it's less efficient to run `cat foo | awk ...` than just `awk ... <foo` or `awk ... foo`; and while that efficiency difference is small for awk in most cases, it can be huge for some other tools -- `wc -c`, `tail` or `sort` are good examples of cases where the delta between `cat file | ...` and `... <file` is huge for large inputs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using GNU userland tools:

```sh
$ cut -d' ' -f 3- input.txt | nl -n ln | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)[[:space:]]*/(\1) /'
(1) pepperoni bacon
(2) banana
(3) winter mountain kiwi
```

Alternatively, you can use a variation of your `awk` script that prints out the `NR` variable (Or `FNR` if you want to process multiple files at once):

```sh
$ awk -v n=3 '{
                printf "(%d) ", NR
                for (i=n; i<=NF; i++)
                  printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
              }' input.txt
(1) pepperoni bacon
(2) banana
(3) winter mountain kiwi
```

(Note removal of the [Useless Use Of Cat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/9952196). Also reformatted for readability).

Or in pure `bash`:

```sh
$ lines=0 && while read -r -a fields; do printf "(%d) %s\n" "$((++lines))" "${fields[*]:2}"; done < input.txt
(1) pepperoni bacon
(2) banana
(3) winter mountain kiwi
```

Comment: No particular need for `read -a`. `while read -r _ _ fields; do ...; done <input.txt` will make `$fields` be a string with third-and-later words on each iteration, as the 1st and 2nd words go into the two `_` placeholder variables.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point. That would probably also let it work on plain `sh`.